# Proper way to respond to "primarily opinion-based" close votes?

Tags: discussion

What is the proper way on SO to respond to close votes cast for a question supposedly "primarily opinion-based"?

I specifically asked for technical (non-opinion) answers in my original question:
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124412/technical-reasons-ivy-has-not-been-commonly-used-as-a-deployment-time-dependency)

I commented on the original question after seeing the close votes (responding to them).

It is frustrating that the question can be voted to close with little more than clicking a radio button dialog and with no further explanation.

Comment: It's still a "Why?" question. Just because you state that you don't want opinions does not mean that it is not likely to attact primarily opinion based answers.

Comment: _Just interested in technical limitations._ - The problem is that your question title asks why people don't use Ivy and any answer to that is going to be a guess (unless someone actually finds a research paper on how organizations choose how to manage/resolve dependencies).

Comment: @BSMP: So I should ask what technical limitations some who tried to use it found?

Comment: The way that's worded would turn it into a polling question, which also doesn't work in a Q&A format. It would be impossible for there to be a "correct" answer if the only criteria is "it was something you experienced". I think my edit took it out of opinion territory though it won't be re-opened if folks think it still has issues.

Answer (score 8):

Consider this example:

> What should my favorite color be?
>
> You should only provide factual answers, rather than your opinions on what color is the best color.

Just because you state that you don't want opinions, or that you only want factual answers, doesn't make the question not primarily opinion based.

---

On a side note, the question is also Too Broad, in addition to being opinion based.

Comment: The limitation of an application for a technical purpose/requirement seems factual to me. Technical requirement = factual. Application meeting/not meeting technical requirement = factual. While dependency resolution could be a large subject, should I ask a separate question for whether Ivy can fulfill each aspect of dependency resolution?

Comment: You would of course have to be specific as to which aspects you are interested in. Just asking for all of them would likely be too broad, and wouldn't be very nice to answerers as then we'd have to go and research to see what all aspects you could possibly be interested in. Also note that some of those "aspects" may also be subjective/primarily opinion based, such as maintainability and ease of use.

Comment: @DonBecker `What are all of the technical limitations of me having Pink as my favorite color?`  Adding the phrase "technical limitations" doesn't automatically remove opinions.  Different people consider different things to be limitations vs advantages.  And again, that's also unquestionably too broad.

Comment: Why did OP waste time writing the question, (technical, factual reasons only)?

Answer (score 1):

Wel,, if a quick scan of the question suggests that the OP is asking for an opinion, the proper way of responding would be to add another close vote.

If the OP also moans about the close voting on meta, I would add a downvote too.

Comment: -1 for suggesting that one wait to downvote until the OP complains on meta.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is make sure your question 1) isn't opinion based 2) doesn't have the same problems as opinion based questions, and 3) isn't too broad.

The [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) page has some guidance that applies here:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - **every answer is equally valid**: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
>     answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I    do.”
> - you are asking an **open-ended**, hypothetical question: “What
>     if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

I bolded those two items because those are the same problems with questions that are too broad and it's likely that questions that are too broad get closed as primarily opinion-based and vice versa. So you have to check for both.

What you want is for your question to be objective and specific. Remove any subjective criteria and wording. If your question is using words like "best", "proper", "easiest", etc. you need to define what that means in measurable terms. (Those terms should be removed altogether.)

Now you may be wondering about subjective questions that are considered good:

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean
>   “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be
>   constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

This is harder to pull off and even questions that fit this criteria may get down and close votes from people who think subjective questions are off topic, no exceptions. If you think your question meets this criteria, you should point to this page in the Help Center (same link as above) and explain how your question meets all of these points and none from the first list.